# Optimizing a django template full of {% regroup %} tags

Tags: django, design-patterns, optimization, django-templates, refactoring

I have a Django template full of nested {% regroup %} tags, and I have the feeling that it is one of the reason why it is so slow. Moreover, it is very complex to maintain like this. Do you have any advise and design patterns to make it faster and more sustainable? I'm open to any suggestion, including moving the logic to models or creating template tags...

Here is a snippet of code, with only the structure, to give you a taste of what it looks like...

```
{% extends "base.tex" %}

{% block content %}
    {% for courseoutline in courseoutline_list %}
        ...

        {% regroup courseoutline.coursemembership_set_by_teaching_unit by teaching_unit as course_list %} 

        {% for course in course_list %}
            {% regroup course.list|dictsort:"course.title" by course.title as course_sublist %}

            {% for course in course_sublist %}
                    {% with course.list|semester:1 as cc %}
                        ...
                        {% for c in cc %}
                        ...
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% endwith %}

                    {% with course.list|semester:2 as cc %}
                        {% for c in cc %}
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% endwith %}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}

        {% regroup courseoutline.coursemembership_set_by_semester by semester as semester_list %} 
        {% for semester in semester_list %}

            {% regroup semester.list by teaching_unit as ue_list %} 

            {% for ue in ue_list %}
                {% for course in ue.list|dictsort:"code" %}
                {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}

        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Thanks!